# Responsive Vertical Aligning Float Right Image and text

Tags: css, image, text

I am very new to this

I am trying to create text next to an floated right image with a background colour that is responsive.
This section will be shown as part of an article but the styling will only apply to this section.

The below code seems to work however i would like the text to be vertically aligned with the image. So that the text is displayed in the middle of the image.

**I dont seem to be able to achieve this**

I have defined 
`<img style="float: right; vertical-align: middle;">`

[Picture of code rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiJIb.jpg)

here is an the code (https://codepen.io/Masseve/pen/LMoMyW/)

```
<div id="blogcontent">   
<img style="float: right; vertical-align: middle;" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-city-interchange-closeup-at-night-beautiful-transport-infrastructure-background-267836915.jpg" width="700"/> 
<div id="textcontent">
<H1> A Title </h1>
<P>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. <br> <br>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</P>                                                                                                                              
</div>
</div>                                                                                                                               

#blogcontent {
border-radius: 4px;
background-color: #ebe9e5;
display: inline-table;
}

#textcontent {
Padding: 20px
}
```

Comment: hello, you should not use floats for this job, you can check the answer below with flex, if you want to learn more about flexbox check here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example :D

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;  
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.main {
  text-align: left;
  background: deepskyblue;
  flex:1.5
}


.aside-1 {
  background: purple;
   flex:1
}
.image{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-image:url('https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-city-interchange-closeup-at-night-beautiful-transport-infrastructure-background-267836915.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
      .aside { flex: 1; }
    }

/*@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .main    { flex: 3 0px; }
  .main    { order: 1; }
  .aside-1 { order: 2; } 
 
}*/
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <article class="main">
   <h1> A Title </h1>
<P>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. <br> <br>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</P>                                                  
                    <br>
                                        <br>
  </article>
  <aside class="aside aside-1">
  <div class="image"></div>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your time but I tried display: flex but I found it was not responsive as it   displays the text and image side by side instead of above the text once breakpoint is reached

Comment: You didn't say you had/wanted a breakpoint. If the code suggested here works for a large screen, then you'll have to write a media query that then moves the text below the image when the viewport gets to a certain width.

Comment: You only play with the float and @mediaquery and you're done.